# TypoScript 'stdWrap.required = 1' not working as expected

Tags: typo3, typoscript, required

I'm trying to render a column with typoscript with values grabbing from cObjects. I've planned like, if there is content then build column,else remove column. By my knowledge, I figured out to use `required = 1`. But result shattered my expectation and questioned my above mentioned 'knowledge' :(

This is what I've configured.

```
FIRST_MODULE = USER_INT
FIRST_MODULE {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  vendorName = dev
  extensionName = devlist
  pluginName = devlist
  controller = devlist
  switchableControllerActions {
    devlist {
      1 = firstmodule
      2 = addtobag
    }
  }
}

SECOND_MODULE = COA
SECOND_MODULE {
  10 = USER_INT
  10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = dev
    extensionName = devlist
    pluginName = devlist
    controller = devlist
    switchableControllerActions {
      devlist {
        1 = secondmodule
        2 = addtobag
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

And now for the column

```
RIGHTCOL = COA
RIGHTCOL {
  10 < FIRST_MODULE
  20 < SECOND_MODULE
  40 < styles.content.getRight
  40 {
    stdWrap {
      wrap = <section class="rightcont">|</section>
      required = 1
    }
  }
  stdWrap {
    wrap = <section class="rightcol">|</section>
    required = 1
  }
}
```

By inspecting in frontend.. Even though called user functions returns nothing and provided no contents in right column

```
<section class="rightcol"></section>
```

There isn't any space or enter between the tags.. I've wrapped the both modules and tested with it, revealing the SECOND_MODULES tag appearing in frontend in the same structure as rightcol(without any space)..

So.. I hope you guyz understood what I'm trying to convey. Consuming lotta coffee and do' nuts for configuring this.. Appreciating in advance,for any help

Comment: Are you sure your Extbase Plugins have no whitespace in the actual source output? Fluid is prone to do that.

Comment: Yup.Totally.. I've checked multiple times to make that sure :(

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 do you use? Did you use `stdWrap.trim = 1`? Did you try using `stdWrap.if.isTrue ...` instead of `stdWrap.required = 1`? Could you tell us what exactly (HTML) is outputted, when there shouldn't be any output?

Comment: I'm using TYPO3 7.6.10 . No usage of stdWrap.trim = 1 and stdWrap.if.isTrue ... If there is no content, I don't want the tags too. I mean, there shouldn't be <section class="rightcol"> .

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code running perfectly. The only difference is the position of required = 1. It is before the wrap.

```
ELEM.stdWrap.required = 1
ELEM.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="wrap">|</div>
```

Comment: That is a perfectly valid answer. It says here the order is important. https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/typoscript/referenz/stdwrap.html